# Use A Bit (bool) Check In A Sql Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to check if someone is out sick, and unfortunately the data is stored in 2 separate tables.  And if they are here, I need to execute path A if they are not here I need to execute path B.  This is what I was thinking but it produces compile error after compile error.  Can someone provide guidance?

```
Create Table #Uno (Id Int Identity, employee varchar(50))
Select empName
From employeeDatabase
WHERE empStatus = 'Active'


Declare @outSick bit, @empName varchar(50), @N int, @MAXID int

Set @N = 1
SELECT @MAXID = Max(ID)
FROM @Uno
WHILE (@N<=MAXID)
BEGIN
--Second Table that stores this data
Select @outSick = callIn
FROM callinDatabase
WHERE empName = @empName

--Returns Yes or True
If @outSick = 1
    Set @N = @N + 1
Else
    --If not out sick Do this sql statement
    Set @N = @N + 1
End
```

Comment: You should not be using a loop here. And what is the point of the IF block at the bottom? It adds 1 to N regardless of the value of outSick.

Comment: You are correct it doesn't need the End If and the End statement I have updated my syntax.  How should I determine which code block to iterate w/o using a loop?

Comment: Both sides are the same here. What are you really trying to do? It looks like maybe you are getting a count of rows by employee where outSick = 1? This can and should be done in a single select statement. Looping if horrible for performance and not needed for things like this.

Comment: I want to get a list of active employees.  Then if the employees are out sick stop proceeding, if they are not out sick run a seperete statement.

Comment: I would suggest that you look into normalizing your tables. Keeping the employee name in multiple tables is not good. What happens when an employee gets married or divorced? Ugh!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do this all in one query, like below?

```
select 
    employeeDatabase.empName,
    case
        when callinDatabase.callin = '1' then 'Out Sick'
        else 'Not Out Sick'
    end as OutSick
from employeeDatabase left join callinDatabase
    on employeeDatabase.empName = callinDatabase.empName
where employeeDatabase.empStatus = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #Uno (Id Int Identity, employee varchar(50))
Select empName
From employeeDatabase
WHERE empStatus = 'Active'


Declare @outSick bit, @empName varchar(50), @N int, @MAXID int

Set @N = 1
SELECT @MAXID = Max(ID)
FROM #Uno                 <----- HERE
WHILE (@N<=@MAXID)        <------- HERE
BEGIN
--Second Table that stores this data
Select @outSick = callIn
FROM callinDatabase
WHERE empName = @empName

--Returns Yes or True
If @outSick = 1
    Set @N = @N + 1
Else
    --If not out sick Do this sql statement
    Set @N = @N + 1
End                      <-------------- Here
```

Comment: I get a syntax error converting varchar to bit.  The varchar value is callin from this line...Select @outSick = callIn